# creating an array or global function to add and removeClasses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment i have several btn on my prototype which toggle classes and remove active classes as demonstrated below. I am wonder if there's a better way of constructing this script such as creating an array?

```
$('#search-btn').click(function () {
    $('.nav-bar-wrap').toggleClass('searchActive');
    $('.more-menu').removeClass('moreMenuActive');
    $('account-menu').removeClass('acMenuActive');
});

$('.more-btn').click(function () {
    $('.more-menu').toggleClass('moreMenuActive');
    $('.account-menu').removeClass('acMenuActive');
    $('.nav-bar-wrap').removeClass('searchActive');
});

$('.ac-btn').click(function () {
    $('.account-menu').toggleClass('acMenuActive');
    $('.nav-bar-wrap').removeClass('searchActive');
    $('.more-menu').removeClass('moreMenuActive');
});

// MOBILE 

$('#mobile-menu').click(function () {
    $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobileMenuActive');
    $('.m-accord-dwn').removeClass('accordionActive');
});

$('.active-mobile-menu').click(function () {
    $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobileMenuActive');
    $('.m-accord-dwn').removeClass('accordionActive');
});

$('.mobile-accordion').click(function () {
    $('.m-accord-dwn').toggleClass('accordionActive');
});
```

Without bombarding this post with hemps of code i have up loaded a snippet of it [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/yg62tdob/18/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is to give the 3 links (more, account, search) a class (ex:btn)
and then use this class to bind the event click,

also add the class (details) to the elements to be shown and hidden after the links

on click event remove the class (visible) from all elements with (details) class then get the next element which is hidden, then add the class (visible) for this element

in the css you should add the class (visible) with visibility:visible

take a look:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $('.details').removeClass('visible');
        $(this).next().addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

html:

```
<a class="inline-block more-btn menu-right btn" href='#' >more</a>
<div class="details small-5 more-menu absolute left z-index-00">
...
...
...
<a class="ac-btn inline-block menu-right btn" href='#' >account</a>
<div class="details small-5 account-menu absolute left z-index-00 right-0">
...
...
...
<a id="search-btn" class="search width-100 small-2 columns btn" href='#' >search</a>
<article class="details small-8 columns search-bar-wrap">
...
...
...
```

css:

```
.more-menu, .account-menu, .search-bar-wrap {visibility: hidden;}

.visible { visibility: visible;}
```

I wish this can help

Comment: this works however it's doesn't remove the class of the previous button

Comment: please take a look at the edited version of my answer